# C#で["aaa","bbb","ccc"]というような文字列から配列を作成するには

Tags: c#, 正規表現

**readme.txt**

```
this file is example file
----------------------
["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"]
```

というような文字列ファイルから配列を作成するにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？

以下の文字列を取り出して、文字列配列を作成したいです。

```
["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"]
```

以下のようなコードで、文字列自体は読み込めますが、文字列配列を作成する方法がわかりません。
できればJsonを使わずに作成したいです。

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(
    "readme.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("Shift_JIS"));

string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

非常にシンプルな文字列になることを想定していて
例えば、["aaa",["bbb","ccc","ddd"]]のような入れ子構造にはならないことを前提としています。また、複数行には分かれず、1行の文字列の中にすべてのデータが含まれることを想定しています。

ダブルクオーテーションと、カンマで区切られるような文字列のみを、文字列配列に変換できると嬉しいです。

Comment: `[ ]`が複数ある/入れ子になっている/`[ ]`やその中の要素が複数行に分かれている、といった何か追加の条件があり得ることを想定していますか？ そうした追加条件の有無や、それがある場合にどのような結果を望んでいるか等を追記してみてください。

Comment: 条件に関して追記を致しました。

Comment: 文字列中に、「[」,「]」,「"」,「,」などの文字を含まないのであれば、「[」,「]」,「"」を削除し、「,」で Split して配列にすれば事足ります。
そうでないなら難易度はハネあがるので json を使うのが得策かと思います。

Comment: > できればJsonを使わずに作成したいです。⇒ 何故ですか？　分からないから？　であればこれを機会に勉強しませんか？　["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"] のような文字列ならJSON のデシリアライザを使う一択だと思いますけど。

Comment: UnityのC#が標準で古いC#になっており、古いバージョンのC#でも動作するようにしたいので、JSONを使いづらいのです。

Comment: 「UnityのC#が標準で古いC#になっており、古いバージョンのC#でも動作するようにしたい」であれば、「できればJsonを使わずに」ではなく、動作バージョンを明記してください。

Comment: 昔、Unity で JSON を扱う際の定番だったらしい MiniJSON は 10 年ぐらい前から存在するようですが、それも使えないということですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

テキストファイルの内容が、あらかじめプログラムに優しい(色々な場合分けや例外の無い)ように作られていると仮定すれば、以下のように出来るでしょう。

読み取ったファイル内容全体から`[ ]`で囲った文字列の抽出

```
int start = text.IndexOf('[');
int len = text.LastIndexOf(']') - start + 1;
string sqbrackets = text.Substring(start, len);
```

これで`sqbrackets`に`["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"]`が入ります。

`sqbrackets`を経由せずにカンマで区切られた文字列の配列にするには、以下のようにします。
文字列配列の作成

```
string csv = text.Substring(start + 1, len - 2);
string[] csarray = csv.Split(',',StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries);
```

これでcsarrayにダブルクォーテーションで囲んだ文字列が配列として格納されます。

`sqbrackets`から作る場合は上記の1行目を以下にします。

```
string csv = sqbrackets.Substring(1, len - 2);
```

以下のようにすれば配列をカンマで連結して1行で表示します。

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',',csarray));
```

---

色々な場合分けや例外的な文字・文字列の扱いをどうするか、といったことも考えるなら、そうした条件を細かくサブルーチン化してチェックするなり、正規表現を使うとかすれば良いと思われます。
正規表現ならこんな記事を参考に：
[Regular Expression for double-quoted values in CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23527369/9014308)
[Parse Microsoft-style CSV data with regex](https://gist.github.com/awwsmm/886ac0ce0cef517ad7092915f708175f)

Answer (score 3):

> できればJsonを使わずに作成したい

の意図は分かりませんが、[`JsonSerializer.Deserialize`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserialize?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-jsonserializer-deserialize(system-string-system-type-system-text-json-jsonserializeroptions))を使えば

```
var text = @"[""aaa"",""bbb"",""ccc"",""ddd""]";

var arr = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(text);
```

で解析できます。`text`は`string`型であり、`arr`は`string[]`型となります。

---

kunifさんが末尾で提案されている正規表現、これを書いてみました。文字列には`[`や`"`が登場し、これを`string`や正規表現としてエスケープする必要があるためわかりづらいです。そこでまずは正規表現のパターンを挙げます。

```
^\["(?<item>[^"]*)"(?:,"(?<item>[^"]*)")*\]$
```

これをソースコード上の文字列として記述するためにエスケープすると

```
var match = Regex.Match(text, @"^\[""(?<item>[^""]*)""(?:,""(?<item>[^""]*)"")*\]$");
var arr = match.Groups["item"].Captures.OfType<Capture>().Select(c => c.Value).ToArray();
```

と表せます。
正規表現では`()`などでマッチした範囲をキャプチャすることができます。また`*`や`+`などの量指定子で複数回マッチさせることができます。一般的な正規表現では複数回マッチした範囲の場合、最後のキャプチャが採用されますが、.NETの正規表現では複数回マッチした場合、`Captures`プロパティを通じてそれぞれのキャプチャ内容にアクセスすることができます。
また一部の正規表では範囲に名前を付けることで名前付きキャプチャが提供されますが、.NETの正規表現では複数個所で同名の名前を付けた場合にキャプチャした内容を統合することができます。
これらの機能を駆使することで`match.Groups["item"].Captures`には`""`に括られた内容を纏めることができます。

Answer (score -4):

ファイルから読んできた文字列 text から、(1) Replace メソッドで [ ] " を削除して、Split メソッドで配列にする方法と、(2) JSON のデシリアライザを使う方法の両方の例を載せておきます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ソースコードを張る場合は画像ではなくてテキストで記述してください。

Comment: 分かりやすさで言えばコードと結果の両方が一目でわかる上の回答のような Visual Studio のデバッグ画面が一番いいと自分では思っているんですけど？　そういう画像を貼ってはいけないということが利用規約にでも書いてあるのですか？　あなたが気に入らないだけでは？

Comment: 画像を張ることはわかりやすくてよいです。私もデバッグやUIの確認ではあるとよりよいでしょう。ですが、コード部分はテキストにしておくと検索エンジンからの検索性があがります。検索性の重要性は[マニフェスト](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto)を参考にしてください、またコードを２次利用する際にもより使いやすいものになります。他者が使いやすいものにするこれも[行動規範](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)に記述があります。

Comment: それでもまだ質問や疑問点がある場合は[メタ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)のほうでぜひ討論や提案をしてみてください。

Comment: 検索を容易にするとか他者が使いやすくすることには異論はありませんが、だからと言って上の回答のようなケースでテキストを強要（ですよね、マイナス評価を付けたようですし）するのは賛成しかねます。

Comment: こちらとしては強要のつもりはございませんでしたが、強要ととらえられてしまったこと言葉が足りなかったことは真摯に謝罪いたします。申し訳ございませんでした。画像だけでも回答が完結していらっしゃるとお思いであればテキストの回答の必要はありません。ほかの人も同じように考えているならきっと自然とプラス評価も増えてくるでしょう。

Comment: 赤の他人に依頼する場合「ソースコードを張る場合は画像ではなくてテキストで記述してください」と「検索エンジンからの検索性があがりますように、画像のコードの部分はテキストでも書いていただけるようお願いします」とどっちが良いですかね？　前者のコメント＆マイナス評価はいかにも上から目線に見えますけど？

Comment: "理由" が (初めから) 説明されていた方がより親切だったかなとは思いますが、その理由もきちんと後から説明がされているので十分意図は伝わっているのではないでしょうか。 / 文字だけでのやり取りは細かなニュアンスが伝えられないので齟齬が起きがちですが、フィードバックはお互いに建設的なものとして発し、受け止めましょう。 / なお、投票はあくまで無記名なので、コメントを残した人が投票したとは限らない点は留意してください。

Comment: 上のあなたのレスも上から目線の余計なお世話です。どこの何様ですか？

Comment: 「上のあなたのレス」がcubickさんのことを指しているのであれば、モデレーターであり[コミュニティを混乱させるような例外的状況に対応するため](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)の発言だと解釈しています。